# Footnotes in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In my PhD thesis I include a bibliography containing my own publications at the beginning. Not all of them are relevant to the PhD thesis though, e.g. because they resulted from my masters. I would like to show this using a footnote or an annotation at the bottom of the reference list.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
    @misc{ref1, note = {Article 1}, keywords={former}, keywords={myarticles}}
    @misc{ref2, note = {Article 2}, keywords={myarticles}}
    @misc{ref3, note = {Proceedings 1}, keywords={former}, keywords={myconferences}}
    @misc{ref4, note = {Proceedings 2}, keywords={myconferences}}
    @misc{ref5, note = {Reference 1}}
    @misc{ref6, note = {Reference 2}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}

    \defbibnote{thepostnote}{* refer to previous work}
    
    \printbibheading[title={References}]
    \newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
    \printbibliography[keyword=myarticles, title={My Articles}, heading=subbibliography, postnote=thepostnote]
    \newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
    \printbibliography[keyword=myconferences, title={My Conference Contributions}, heading=subbibliography, postnote=thepostnote]
    \newrefcontext
    \printbibliography[notkeyword=myarticles, notkeyword=myconferences, title={Regular References}, heading=subbibliography, resetnumbers=true]


\end{document}
```

Ideally, the entries should look like this:

> [A1]* Article 1
>
> [A2]  Article 2
>
> * refer to previous work

Currently, my workaround is to split the subbibliographies into two parts and use `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=*A]` and `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]`, respectively. This is kind of ugly though, preferably the star should appear *after* the bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to give several `keywords` you must give them in the same `keywords` field separated with a comma.

Secondly, and more interestingly, you can add a star by redefining the `labelnumberwidth` format.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
  \ifkeyword{former}
    {\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsuperscript{*}}}
    {}}
```

The `\ifkeyword` and `\textsuperscript{*}` should be self-explanatory. I wrapped the `\textsuperscript{*}` in a `\makebox[0pt][l]` so that the asterisk does not take up any space. Normally the numbers are right-aligned and if the asterisk took up space the closing bracket of `[A2]` would align with the right end of `[A1]*` and we'd get

> ```
> [A1]*
>  [A2]
> ```

instead of

> ```
> [A1]*
> [A2]
> ```

The alternative would have been to left-align the labels, but that would result in

> ```
> [8]
> [9]
> [10]
> ```

instead of

> ```
>  [8]
>  [9]
> [10]
> ```

If you have a current `biblatex` version you may also be interested in the option `locallabelwidth` to avoid excess space in the last bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true, locallabelwidth]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
  \ifkeyword{former}
    {\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsuperscript{*}}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ref1, note = {Article 1}, keywords={former,myarticles}}
@misc{ref2, note = {Article 2}, keywords={myarticles}}
@misc{ref3, note = {Proceedings 1}, keywords={former,myconferences}}
@misc{ref4, note = {Proceedings 2}, keywords={myconferences}}
@misc{ref5, note = {Reference 1}}
@misc{ref6, note = {Reference 2}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\defbibnote{thepostnote}{* refer to previous work}

\printbibheading[title={References}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[keyword=myarticles, title={My Articles}, heading=subbibliography, postnote=thepostnote]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[keyword=myconferences, title={My Conference Contributions}, heading=subbibliography, postnote=thepostnote]
\newrefcontext
\printbibliography[notkeyword=myarticles, notkeyword=myconferences, title={Regular References}, heading=subbibliography, resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

[image: Superscript-star to mark <code>former</code> contributions.]